# Magento 2 custom admin router overwrite model

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to override model class with custom model class only when going to custom url?
Example:When going to

> http://example.com/admin/adminhtml/sitemap/index/key/aa6f86507bb01ef052dc1baf515d87ca9a3b3098f6d2aa474c4b1e080b3d0775/

uses core model on generation.
Now I want when going to my custom route

> http://example.com/admin/customproduct/sitemap/index/key/aa6f86507bb01ef052dc1baf515d87ca9a3b3098f6d2aa474c4b1e080b3d0775/

rewrite core model with di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap" type="Product\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extending Adminhtml controller generate action class execute method, change model load to your desired model. In my case it was:

```
$sitemap = $this->_objectManager->create(\Product\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap::class);
    /* @var $sitemap \Product\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap */
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would be injecting your class , Product\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap, to your Custom Controller's __construct method,

I would suggest, just extend your Custom Sitemap class to the Core Sitemap class.

Assuming that you have a function or method which you wanted to customize from the 'Core' Sitemap, declare the method in your custom sitemap, make the necessary customization and return the required response.

Let me know how it goes.